# Most secure way to encrypt critical data to be shared, edited and seen (must ALWAYS be secure)

Tags: networking, local-area-network, encryption, cloud, security

This question does not rely on time... so it's not about keeping data on tape or anything similar.

I have 3 distinct PCs with critical information. PCs are running Windows OS. They all hold critical data that needs to be secure at all time (encrypted).

I'm trying to find a way to secure the data on the PCs at all time, while letting them share the data, edit it and view it. Right now PCs are encrypted and each have their own key to decrypt, so I need to use a FAT32 external HDD to transfer data (which is now unencrypted since it's not an NTFS partition and I use Windows encryption). I want to eradicate the physical part of the datasharing process and share the files locally and securely.

We are looking looking into the option of buying a server and make a local crypted cloud, but I'm open to better ways of doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Protect files on NTFS volume from Domain Administrators](http://serverfault.com/questions/387651/protect-files-on-ntfs-volume-from-domain-administrators)